# SQL Server - Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference

Tags: sql-server

I get the error when I run this

```
SELECT Tags
FROM Company  
WHERE Tags IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(LEN(Tags) - LEN(REPLACE(Tags, token, ''))) / LEN(token) AS score
          FROM (VALUES ('tokena'), ('tokenb'), ('tokenc')) AS X(token)) DESC
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: what's the error, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: `ORDER BY` should be followed by a **column name** (potentially multiple) - but you seem to be calculating a number........ what exactly are you trying to do here, really???